# Spring Security : BadCredentialsException is thrown instead of LockedException, why?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I was trying to catch exception of LockedException, but it throws BadCredentialsException instead.

```
try {
    accessToken = accessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(
                    resourceDetails,
                    new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());

} catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException e) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException('invalid login', authentication.details);
} catch (Exception e) {
    authenticationErrorReporter.logSessionData(session)
    throw e
}
```

When a locked account try to get accessToken, first do this

```
preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
```

It throws AuthenticationException, then transfer to AccountStatusException, after that, I got InvocationTargetException, and then caught by OAuth2AccessDeniedException. 
What I want is AccountStatusException, not OAuth2AccessDeniedException.

Here is the Stacktrace

```
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - InvalidGrantException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/oauth/token - parameters:
    username: someone
    grant_type: password
    password: ***
    User account is locked. Stacktrace follows:
    error="invalid_grant", error_description="User account is locked"
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:179)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem, appreciate that.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: @reos Hi, I added the stacktrace info, could you please take a look at it again.

Comment: If the exception is thrown in obtainAccessToken method, that is not the corresponding stacktrace. If you see the Stacktrace the exception AccountStatusException is never thrown. I think you need see where exactly the exception is thrown.